# Linux HP 15 mute key light

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, mute

I own HP 15-db0038nc laptop.
It has LED on mute key, which indicates if sound is muted or not. It works on Windows, but it doesn't work in Linux (Xubuntu 18.04). I don't see it in `alsamixer`. This is what I see when i use `aspi_listen` and press mute key:

`button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K`

Any ideas what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (HP Pavilion x360) this works:

```
sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-hp-x360" >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

The sources are:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/f3h0dp/hp_pavilion_mute_led_will_never_switch_on_any/)
- [wiki.mbirth.de](https://wiki.mbirth.de/know-how/hardware/hp-spectre-x360/mute-led.html)

Answer (score 0):

For my HP Pavilion 14-bf000 laptop, @serhumanos' answer *kinda* worked, but I noticed that it linked the LED to **only** the built-in speakers. So e.g. when I plugged in headphones, the LED would reflect the mute state of the speakers, **NOT** the headphones.

I found that a different hda model (`hp-mute-led-mic3`) fixed this problem for me. Concretely, create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/mute.conf`*  with the contents

```
options snd-hda-intel model=hp-mute-led-mic3
```

* I think the filename doesn't matter - it just has to be in the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory, and end in `.conf`.

Comment: There is a list of models here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.2/sound/hd-audio/models.html

Comment: Mute / Mic mute were significantly reworked in recent kernels. As of 5.10 (I think?) they're now actual "LED devices" that have independent configuration from the snd-hda module.

Comment: Well, this works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, whereas the default configuration doesn't.